# I accidentally delete /usr/local/var, what should I do?

Tags: macos, homebrew, file-recovery

I ran this accidentally because I want to remove sql completely:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var
```

What should I do now?

I know the `var` folder contained `homebrew`, `mysql` and `run` folder before.

I don't care about `mysql` folder because I want to get rid of it but how can I recover `homebrew` and `run` folder?

Or does it matter? What should I do now to be safe in future?

Debugging info:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.6.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 7dac; last commit 2018-06-20)
```

System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77)

Kernel Version: Darwin 17.6.0

Comment: Restore from backups or reinstall?

Comment: Given that you mention homebrew, can we presume macOS? If so, what version?

Comment: The fastest way is to restore /usr/local/var from time machine before rebooting. This way you'll only lose what changed in homebrew during this short period of time.

Comment: It's a new machine, I didn't turn on time machine and backup yet

Comment: It's MacOS,  System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77), Kernel Version: Darwin 17.6.0

Answer (score 0):

As you have no backup, then re-installing the OS will at least return it to its initial state.

It will do this without changing anything other than system files. No apps/data are lost.

You can run it from Recovery -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at boot.